VLC not working properly
Ubuntu 24.04
VLC ver: 3.0.20 Vetinari
Open VLC start a movie the Menu commands work properly the commands on bottom don’t respond as should  click on Play, Pause, Stop or any part of the screen it goes off the screen but the movie and sound carry’s on to close VLC I have to Quit on VLC icon.
Need help to fix this.
Thank you

Have you visited the VLC support site to see if they have updated VLC to work with Ubuntu 24.04?

suggest you purge and install the flatpak version.

Did you install VLC from the command line (with APT) or from the Snap store (GUI)?

I install both from Snap store and the Debian store had the same problem.

For what it is worth - 3.0.20-3build6 installed with sudo apt install vlc on 24.04; works just fine here.

Just install vlc as suggested still goes off the screen when click.

Just to reiterate, if you install it with sudo apt install vlc it will install 3.0.20-3build6 and it will install a lot of dependencies and it will work just fine.
